# Verify users on my app with Amazon Account Linking

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, alexa-skills-kit, account-linking

How can I verify that a user that has logged in with Amazon or Google on a cloud service is the same user as the one I've on my application?

Scenario: I've a website were the user has an account. I want to allow an alexa skill from a third party to access my app api.

I've read about account linking, from this article:
https://developer.amazon.com/es/blogs/post/Tx3CX1ETRZZ2NPC/Alexa-Account-Linking-5-Steps-to-Seamlessly-Link-Your-Alexa-Skill-with-Login-wit

> There are many ways you can use account linking to enhance your Alexa skills. For example:
>
> You can map this user profile to an existing user in your user database, using the email address as key. This would allow you to create a contextual skill that behaves according to your user’s preferences and history.

The third party sends me some authentication token that I can use to get data from the user from Amazon AWS and verify that is the same email?

Comment: What exactly is the question you are asking? The article you've linked explains how to do what you are describing. Is there a specific part where you are getting stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume your user has linked the account with your skill and the request contains the filed accessToken in alexaRequestBody['context']['System']['user']. For more information on the accessToken check this [link](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/add-account-linking-logic-custom-skill.html#get-token) out. Then the second thing you'll need to do is to make an GET request to the Amazon Profile API.

Request example: GET [https://api.amazon.com/user/profile?access_token=${$alexaRequestBody['context']['System']['user']['accessToken']}](https://api.amazon.com/user/profile?access_token=$%7B$alexaRequestBody%5B%27context%27%5D%5B%27System%27%5D%5B%27user%27%5D%5B%27accessToken%27%5D%7D)

This way you can know what user Amazon Users are interacting with your API.

I hope that I have managed to help you. In case you are using WordPress you can check out our WordPress plugin [Convoworks WP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/convoworks-wp/) which enables you to create Alexa Skills directly from your WordPress site.